# Is XML really extensible?

Tags: xml, parsing, extensibility

I work a lot with XML and JSON and many system platforms throw error in the deserialization process when you add a new field to the structure, error is because they are not expecting the new field. Is not supposed that X in XML is for extensibility, and extensibility is not about "extend" something?

Comment: "This is a plate of spaghetti. I changed the recipe and added a quart of motor oil. You should like it, because it's still spaghetti". XML might be extensible, but if you change the semantics of the document, then it's a diffferent document.

Comment: My point of view is more like, "This is a plate of spaghetti. but if you want, I leave you a condiment of motor oil to add to your spaghetti"

Comment: nope. you're mixed in the motor oil by adding that field. if that field is not present in the XML's DTD, then it's an unknown/invalid field and the document will fail to validate. And of course, apps can be written to ALWAYS expect the document to have a certain structure, and if they expect `<a /><b /><c />` and you suddenly start sending `<a /><c /><b />`, they'll barf.

Comment: Extensibility doesn't mean that you can change interfaces or contracts without informing the clients or consumers.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "system platforms", but you seem to be complaining that the XML is extensible but the "system platforms" aren't. Doesn't that answer your question? This is one reason why people recommend writing applications to use XML "end to end" rather than mixing it with technologies that are less extensible.

Comment: I know about contract and limitation of it, that is the reason why I saw a lot o "blank contracts" where there a field "data" with `<![CDATA[]]>`.